# Group by YYYYMM from YYYYMMDD int column - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have date in yyyymmdd format in an int column and I would like to group by month i.e. yyyymm.I've tried the below two versions

```
 select to_char(to_timestamp(create_dt),'YYYYMM'),count(*)  from table_name
 group by to_char(to_timestamp(create_dt),'YYYYMM')
 order by to_char(to_timestamp(create_dt),'YYYYMM') desc
```

AND

```
 select to_char(create_dt,'YYYYMM'),count(*)  from table_name
 group by to_char(create_dt,'YYYYMM')
 order by to_char(create_dt,'YYYYMM') desc
```

Comment: What happened when you tried those versions?

Comment: @lurker got just 1 row with your query similar to the second one I have posted. "YYYYMM";733103965. I converted the column to a string and used substring to groupby the 1st 6 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select create_dt / 100, count(*)
from t
group by 1
order by 1 desc
limit 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,any alternate ways would be helpful.

```
 select substring(create_dt::int8,1,6),count(*)  from table
 group by substring(create_dt::int8,1,6)
 order by substring(create_dt::int8,1,6) desc
 limit 6;
```

Comment: how you plan substr for int8? - may be `substring(create_dt,1,6)::int8`?